# Python BeautifulSoup find_all re.compile finding anything within a set of tags

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Here is my html data:

```
<td>4.2.2</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.zip">zip</a> (<a  href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.zip.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.zip.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-.2.2.tar.gz">tar.gz</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.tar.gz.md5">md5</a>|<ahref="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.tar.gz.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2-IIS.zip">IISzip</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2-IIS.zip.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2-IIS.zip.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td>4.2.1</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.zip">zip</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.zip.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.zip.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.tar.gz">tar.gz</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.tar.gz.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.tar.gz.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1-IIS.zip">IIS zip</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1-IIS.zip.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1-IIS.zip.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td>4.2</td>
<td>1.0-platinum</td>
```

etc..

I would like iterate down the page and pull out only version numbers within:

```
<td>4.2.2</td>
```

tags. Ex:

4.2.2

4.2.1

4.2

1.0-platinum

So far I have tried:

```
for tag in html.find_all('tbody', limit=1, string=re.compile("\<td\>(.*?)\<\/td\>")):
print(tag.content)
```

nothing

```
rpart=html.find('tbody')
for tds in rpart.find_all('td'):
print(tds.find_all('\<td\>(.*?)\<\/td>'))
```

nothing

```
results=rpart.find_all('td', tds=re.compile("\<td\>(.*?)\<\/td\>"))
```

nothing

```
wphtml.find('tbody').find_all('td', tds=re.compile('\<td\>(.*?)\<\/td\>'))
```

nothing

```
 for p in rpart.find_all('td', digits=re.compile('\<td\>(.*?)\<\/td\>')):
 print(p.contents)
```

nothing

I did notice that rpart is type "ResultSet", so I am willing to bet its something little that I am missing. What on gods earth am I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is a missing space in the last  tag in the third . That might be causing problems parsing using BeautifulSoup.

There are two ways you can pull this off easily with the text you provided:

1. BeautifulSoup:

   ```
   html = BeautifulSoup(htmlString, 'html.parser')
   for tag in html.find_all('td', align=None):
       print(tag.string)
   ```
2. Pure Regex (no BeautifulSoup):

   ```
   for val in re.findall(re.compile('\<td\>(.*?)\<\/td\>'), htmlString):
       print val
   ```

Best I can tell, because BeautifulSoup is searching through tag names when using the "find_all" function, the re.compile will use regex to find tag names that match the pattern.  For example, if you wanted to find all "tbody" and "td" tags, you could use this:

```
for tag in html.find_all(re.compile('t[d|b]')):
    print tag.string
```

From the tag that is found, you can then access attributes or the value/string within the opening and closing tag.  I've not found a way to use BeautifulSoup to find tags by their values/strings.

Here's a reference with a couple of examples in case it helps:  [BeautifulSoup Documentation - A Regular Expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)

Also, in BeautifulSoup, the re.compile in a "find_all" is used for "filtering/matching", not for capture groups.  Meaning, the regex is a pattern to match.  You can't use (.*?) to extract part of the value for comparison in this situation.

Comment: Awesome, I would still like to know why any of my methods using re.compile and BeautifuilSoup would not work.

Comment: My comment got too long, so I updated the response above with more detail to try to answer your question.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Correct regex is `<td>(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)</td>`. Using `re.findall` does not need BeautifulSoup:

```
import re
html = """
<td>4.2.2</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.zip">zip</a> (<a  href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.zip.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.zip.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-.2.2.tar.gz">tar.gz</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.tar.gz.md5">md5</a>|<ahref="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2.tar.gz.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2-IIS.zip">IISzip</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2-IIS.zip.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.2-IIS.zip.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td>4.2.1</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.zip">zip</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.zip.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.zip.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.tar.gz">tar.gz</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.tar.gz.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1.tar.gz.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td align="center"><a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1-IIS.zip">IIS zip</a> (<a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1-IIS.zip.md5">md5</a> | <a href="https://blah.org/blah-4.2.1-IIS.zip.sha1">sha1</a>)</td>,
<td>4.2</td>
"""
print re.findall("<td>(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*)</td>", html)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Unfortunately, I am stuck using BeautifulSoup. I forgot to add to my original post that some of the text within the td tags have characters so thats why I had my regex specified in such a way to grab it all.